# $f\in L^1\cap L^2$ with $\|f\|_1=a, \|f\|_2=b$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

For $a,b\in (0,\infty)$ arbitrary is it possible to find a function $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)\cap L^2(\mathbb R)$ with $\|f\|_1=a$ and $\|f\|_2=b$ ? I think this is possible but I haven't such a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, take

$$
f(x)=\frac{b^2}{a}\chi_{(0,a^2/b^2)}(x)
$$

Comment: How do you even come up with this formula? Well, take an interval $[0,d]$ and the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}c&&x\in[0,d]\\0&&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ and then write the expressions for $a=||f||_1$ and $b=||f||_2$ as functions of $c, d$, then solve for $c, d$.